# Convert text file into excel with delimiter and text formatted columns vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, csv, dataformat

I'd like to convert a .txt file into Excel with a VBScript. I have a character that I would like to delimit "|". I would also like to format column data as text before the text is opened. This is what I'm currently using minus the formatting of column data as text.

```
Const xlDelimited                =  1
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook          = 51

xl.Workbooks.OpenText "C:\project\project.txt", , , xlDelimited, , , , , , , True, "|"

Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook

wb.SaveAs "C:\project\project.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook, , , , False
wb.Close

xl.Quit
```

I need help with formatting the column data as text before the text file is opened. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. My attempts yielded the columns being formatted as text after the file was opened causing the loss of numerical data starting with zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [schema.ini file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to describe the structure/data types of your .txt file. Excel should obey those definitions.

Comment: This is a step in part of a task automation. And is running as part of a larger script. This step converts the text file with the mentioned parameters and saves it as an .xlsx. Does your solution fit with what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The `FieldInfo` parameter of the [`OpenText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) method takes an array of 2-element arrays (column number and format specifier). Try this:

```
Const xlTextFormat = 2

fieldInfo = Array( Array(1, xlTextFormat) _
  , Array(2, xlTextFormat) _
  , Array(3, xlTextFormat) _
  , ...
)

xl.Workbooks.OpenText "C:\project\project.txt", , , xlDelimited, , , , , , _
  , True, "|", fieldInfo
```